# multiple self joins or unions in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, self-join

I have this dummy  temptable that looks like this

```
      ID     Sum    Indicator       Month    Year
       1     10     Ind1             3       2016
       1     20     Ind2             3       2016
       2     15     Ind1             3       2016
       2     19     Ind3             3       2016
       .     .      .                .       .
       .     .      .                .       . 
       50    5      Ind1             3       2016
       50    5      Ind2             3       2016
       50    5      Ind3             3       2016
```

What I want to get as result is the following:

```
 ID    Ind1     Ind2    Ind3    Month    Year
 1     10       20      null    3        2016
 2     15       null    19      3        2016
 50    5        5       5       3        2016
```

What I have tried:

```
   select  a.ID,b.sum as Ind1,c.sum as Ind2,d.sum as Ind3  
   from (
          ( 
          dummytable a 
          left join dummytable b 
          on a.ID=b.ID
          )
        left join dummytable c 
        on a.ID=c.ID
        ) 
   left join dummytable d 
   on a.ID=d.ID 
   where b.Indicator=Ind1  and c.Indicator=Ind2 and d.Indicator=Ind3
```

This bit captures all those ID that have values for Ind1,2,3 so from my example displays only the last row of the desired result. I know that since Access doesnt support full joins union should be used to capture the rest of the combinations. However, I continue this with union I either get an error message( join expression not supported) or duplicate values of the same results. Any suggestions?

Comment: MS Access supports cross tab queries which will allow you to pivot on indicator and use sum as the values portion while grouping by ID, Month and year.  I see no reason for all the self joins.  [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVFgjMDeGaw) showing how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, consider MS Access' unique pivot query, the [crosstab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8), which is a listed object in the Access UI Create ribbon query tab. In the design view, you would select columns in two `GROUP BY` types (except `Values` last being aggregate type)

1. Row Heading fields (e.g., ID, Month, Year) - can be multiple table columns
2. Column Heading field (e.g., Indicator) - can only be **one** where column result in separate columns
3. Values field (e.g., Sum) - can only be **one** column using an aggregate function - Sum(), Max(), Avg(), etc.

The resulting SQL will be created (notice the aggregate query embedded):

```
TRANSFORM Sum(dummytable.Sum) AS SumOfSum
SELECT dummytable.ID, dummytable.Month, dummytable.Year
FROM dummytable
GROUP BY dummytable.ID, dummytable.Month, dummytable.Year
PIVOT dummytable.Indicator;
```

With results

```
ID  Month   Year    Ind1    Ind2    Ind3
1   3       2016    10      20  
2   3       2016    15              19
50  3       2016    5       5       5
```

---

For a generalized RDMS pivot query to work outside Access, simply use conditional aggregates. Do note in other SQL dialects, `IIF()` function will have to be replaced with `CASE/WHEN` or `IF/THEN`:

```
SELECT dummytable.ID, dummytable.Month, dummytable.Year,
          SUM(IIF(dummytable.Indicator = 'Ind1', [Sum], NULL)) As Ind1,
          SUM(IIF(dummytable.Indicator = 'Ind2', [Sum], NULL)) As Ind2,
          SUM(IIF(dummytable.Indicator = 'Ind3', [Sum], NULL)) As Ind3

FROM dummytable
GROUP BY dummytable.ID, dummytable.Month, dummytable.Year;
```

Comment: you are both correct, crosstab will do the job. However, I am after a more generic SQL query that does the same job and can run directly or with minimum changes to a SQL-server environment (planned migration). Thank you for your help

Comment: No worries. See additional pivot query to work across SQL dialects. You will have to know the Indicators in advance.

Answer (score -1):

To create a Multiple Value Field crosstab query, you must create a separate crosstab query for each value that you want to calculate. You can then use a select query to join these crosstab queries to display the results that you want.